# Touchpad issues

Tags: touchpad

I have a Medion Akoya E6241 Notebook.

I have done a fresh installation of Freya.

Since installation the touchpad has not worked, and I have to use a usb mouse.

Terminal input list is:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Dell Dell USB Mouse                       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have ensured that touchpad is turned on in mouse and touch pad settings. I have also played around with all options there in to no avail.

My BIOS does not give any options for the touch pad.

I have attempted to enable the touchpad using `xinput set-prop 4 "Device Enabled" 1`, unfortunately this has no effect.

I tried to disable the touchpad also, and i get this error message:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  21
```

Can anyone please suggest what may be the issue and how to go about fixing it?

Thanks for taking time to read this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://askubuntu.com/a/528429/138887 Mine is not detected by any Linux distro either that's how I make it work.

> You have to add "i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop" to the kernel boot options. You can do this permanently by adding these arguments to the "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" attribute in the file /etc/default/grub. Then it looks like this.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

After that you just need to enter this command and reboot:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: This should be rather a comment than an answer. Answers should give a solution, ideally with some descriptions why it works, what's the problem, etc. Please convert it to a comment.

Comment: @bigbang says who and according to what? I give this guy a solid solition from my own experience. This is an answer. Go troll someone else.

Comment: Did you have a bad day?